# Can't get a JOOQ DSL context

Tags: jooq, r2dbc

I am trying to build a minimal example using Postgres, JOOQ and Flyway.

I expect a context to be generated, when I pass a connection factory configured for r2dbc:

```
@Configuration
class R2DBC(
    @Value("\${spring.r2dbc.url}") val url: String,
    @Value("\${spring.r2dbc.username}") val username: String,
    @Value("\${spring.r2dbc.password}") val password: String
) {
    @Bean
    fun r2dbcConnectionFactory(): ConnectionFactory = ConnectionFactories.get(
        ConnectionFactoryOptions
            .parse(url)
            .mutate()
            .option(ConnectionFactoryOptions.USER, username)
            .option(ConnectionFactoryOptions.PASSWORD, password)
            .build()
    )
}

@SpringBootApplication
class CoRoutineJooqApplication {

    @Bean
        fun jooqDSLContext(connectionFactory: ConnectionFactory): DSLContext =
        DSL.using(connectionFactory)

}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<CoRoutineJooqApplication>(*args)
}
```

But when I inject it

```
@Component
class ApplicationRunner(private val ctx: DSLContext) : ApplicationRunner {

    override fun run(args: ApplicationArguments?) {
        printTableInformation()
    }

    private fun printTableInformation(): Unit = ctx.meta().tables.forEach { table -> println("Table: ${table.name}") }
}
```

the context has no connection provider and I get the exception **"Caused by: org.jooq.exception.DetachedException: No JDBC Connection provided by ConnectionProvider".**

I am also using Flyway and JOOQ code generation via JDBC.

```
@Configuration
class FlywayConfig(private val env: Environment) {

    @Bean(initMethod = "migrate")
    fun flyway(): Flyway = Flyway(
            Flyway.configure()
                .baselineOnMigrate(false)
                .dataSource(
                    env.getRequiredProperty("spring.flyway.url"),
                    env.getRequiredProperty("spring.flyway.user"),
                    env.getRequiredProperty("spring.flyway.password")
                )
        )
}
```

These are my **application properties**:

```
spring:
  jooq:
    sql-dialect: postgres
  r2dbc:
    url: r2dbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/demo
    username: postgres
    password: postgres
  flyway:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/demo
    user: ${spring.r2dbc.username}
    password: ${spring.r2dbc.password}
    enabled: true
    schemas: demo
```

and my **build file**

```
import nu.studer.gradle.jooq.JooqGenerate
import org.jooq.meta.jaxb.*
import org.jooq.meta.jaxb.Logging

group = "demo.eisenbarth"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
description = "Demo Reactive Spring Boot With Kotlin Coroutines And JOOQ"


object Versions {
    const val KOTLINX = "1.7.3"
    const val JOOQ = "3.18.6"
    const val SPRING ="3.1.4"
    const val R2DBC_POSTGRES = "1.0.2.RELEASE"
}

// We configure JDBC and R2DBC since Jooq code generation and flyway rely on JDBC and Spring can only autoconfigure one.
data class JdbcDataSource(
    val driver: String = System.getenv("driver") ?: project.property("driver") as String,
    val jdbcUrl: String = System.getenv("jdbc_url") ?: project.property("jdbc_url") as String,
    val username: String = System.getenv("username") ?: project.property("username") as String,
    val password: String = System.getenv("password") ?: project.property("password") as String
)
val dbConfig = JdbcDataSource()

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.1.4"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.3"
    id("nu.studer.jooq") version "8.2.1"
    id("org.flywaydb.flyway") version "9.22.1"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.9.10"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.9.10"
}

dependencies {

    // coroutines
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-reactor") // Reactor/Coroutine-Bridge
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-slf4j") // MDC
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-reactive") // NEEDED ???

    // marshalling
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")

    // web
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation")

    // database
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc")
    implementation("org.postgresql:r2dbc-postgresql:${Versions.R2DBC_POSTGRES}") // reactive postgres driver
    // implementation("org.springframework:spring-jdbc")
    implementation("org.postgresql:postgresql") // flyway and jooq code generation uses jdbc

    // flyway
    implementation("org.flywaydb:flyway-core")

    // jooq
    jooqGenerator("org.postgresql:postgresql")
    implementation("org.jooq:jooq:${Versions.JOOQ}}")
    implementation("org.jooq:jooq-kotlin")
    implementation("org.jooq:jooq-kotlin-coroutines")
    // What about: spring-boot-starter-jooq?
    // Don't need it, because we use studer's plugin to configure JOOQ also it depends on spring-boot-starter-jdbc.

    // test
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testImplementation("io.projectreactor:reactor-test")
}

flyway {
    println("Configuring Flyway")
    driver = dbConfig.driver
    url = dbConfig.jdbcUrl
    user = dbConfig.username
    password = dbConfig.password
    locations = arrayOf("filesystem:./src/main/resources/db/migration")
    placeholders = mapOf("schema_name" to "demo")
}

// Configure jooq plugin. Make sure this comes before configuring tasks, otherwise "generateJooq" will be unknown.
jooq {
    version.set("${Versions.JOOQ}")
    edition.set(nu.studer.gradle.jooq.JooqEdition.OSS)
    configurations {
        create(name = "main") {
            generateSchemaSourceOnCompilation.set(true)
            jooqConfiguration.apply {
                logging = Logging.WARN
                jdbc.apply {
                    driver = dbConfig.driver
                    url = dbConfig.jdbcUrl
                    user = dbConfig.username
                    password = dbConfig.password
                }
                generator.apply {
                    name = "org.jooq.codegen.KotlinGenerator"
                    database.apply {
                        name = "org.jooq.meta.postgres.PostgresDatabase"
                        inputSchema = "demo"
                        includes = ".*"
                        isIncludeIndexes = false
                        // Excludes match before includes, i.e. excludes have a higher priority.
                        excludes = "flyway.*"
                        schemaVersionProvider = "SELECT MAX(\"version\") FROM \"flyway_schema_history\""
                        // Give enough time to jOOQ to trigger the queries needed for generating sources
                        logSlowQueriesAfterSeconds = 20
                    }

                    generate.apply {
                        withPojosAsKotlinDataClasses(true)
                        //withSpringAnnotations(true)
                        //withSpringDao(true)
                        //withValidationAnnotations(true)
                        //withKotlinNotNullRecordAttributes(true)
                        //withImplicitJoinPathsAsKotlinProperties(true)
                        //withUdts(true)
                    }
                    // Prefix generated Pojos with 'Jooq'
                    strategy.withMatchers(
                        Matchers()
                            .withTables(
                                arrayOf(
                                    MatchersTableType()
                                        .withPojoClass(
                                            MatcherRule()
                                                .withExpression("Jooq_$0")
                                                .withTransform(MatcherTransformType.PASCAL)
                                        )
                                ).toList()
                            )
                    )

                    target.apply {
                        packageName = "jooq.generated"
                        directory = "build/generated-sources"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// There's only one module / one KotlinCompile task, so we don't need to configure all tasks via the type.
tasks {
    compileKotlin {
        kotlinOptions {
            freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
            jvmTarget = "17"
        }
    }
    test {
        useJUnitPlatform()
    }
    // Configure jOOQ code generation task such that it only executes when something that potentially affects code generation has changed.
    named<JooqGenerate>("generateJooq") {

        // Ensure database schema has been prepared by Flyway before generating the jOOQ sources.
        dependsOn("flywayMigrate")

        // Declare Flyway migration scripts as inputs on the jOOQ task.
        inputs.files(fileTree("${rootDir}/src/main/resources/db/migration"))
            .withPropertyName("migrations")
            .withPathSensitivity(PathSensitivity.RELATIVE)

        // Make jOOQ task participate in incremental builds and build caching.
        allInputsDeclared.set(true)
        outputs.cacheIf { true }

    }
}
```

I've tried to follow the example provided by kamilgregorczyk in this [thread](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/26439),
but I don't know what I am missing here, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jOOQ `Meta` API is based on JDBC, not R2DBC, and you're not injecting your JDBC connection into your `DSLContext`, so it can't run queries on the JDBC `DatabaseMetaData`.

To solve this, create a `DSLContext` using your JDBC `Connection`, instead.